# Shopware theme config; "Unable to find setter for config field "scss"

Tags: shopware

Via the shopware documentation I set up the following field via the `theme.json`

```
"fields": {
    "sw-footer-contact-details": {
        "label": {
            "en-GB": "Footer contact"
        },
        "type": "text",
        "scss": false,
        "custom": {
            "componentName": "sw-text-editor"
        },
        "block": "footerBlock",
        "section": "Contact"
    }
}
```

But when accessing the frontend i get the following error; `Unable to find setter for config field "scss"`. It is because of the `"scss": false` line. The part of the documentation prescribing this is https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/theme-guide/configuration?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/theme-guide#config-fields

Comment: Which Shopware version are you using exactly?